# AVPlayer stops playing video when I enter the background using the home button

Tags: swift

I have an **AVPlayer** inside of an **AVPlayerLooper** playing a local video file (MP4). It works until the app enters the background. When I reopen the app, the video is paused. How can I ensure that it is playing when I reopen the app? Thank you very much, Hans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a common issue of the AVPlayer framework. The fix however is quite simply assuming that your AVPlayer is inside a regular view. Firstly, make your videoPlayer or the view that it is inside a global variable. You do this by declaring it outside of any class. Then you need to go to your **AppDelegate** file and make these changes:

```
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

        yourVideoPlayerView.player?.play()

    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. Anything I need to be careful about with a global variable?

Comment: Yes, I recommend keeping track of all places within your project that access or modify the global variable. You need to maintain an overview! Other than that there should be no issue. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

About the global variable, you should not use it. Using global variables is almost always (if not always) a bad idea. But I'm sure you already now (since you're asking about it in your second comment).

You can use Notification Center to listen for notifications for app going to foreground or background like this:

```
let applicationForegroundObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: { [weak self](notification) in
        // Here you can resume playback in your case, or do whatever you need
    })
```

This notification can be used from wherever you want. So maybe it's an idea if you use this in the view controller where you have the player. Maybe you can register for these notifications on viewDidAppear and unregister on viewDidDisappear or something like that. Or maybe just register on the viewDidLoad. (It depends on what you want to achieve)

Comment: Thank you, so far the global variable is working but if I run into problems with it I will resort to your approach. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Global variable always work. Until they don't.. and when they don't it's usually painful.
In my honest opinion, it's better to lose 10 minutes now and avoid bad practice than 10 days later when you are forced to fix a bug you won't even realize it's due to that global variable you introduced some months earlier.

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to this. What kind of reasons can there be for a global variable causing a bug except for me getting messy code and altering it from all over the place? As long as i keep track of the places from where I access and edit it I should be fine or?

Comment: That is completely out of the scope of the thread but in 2 words: you could beed more than one player one day. You may want to configure them in two ways. Even if you only want to show it in 1 view controller, that view controller is not a single global variable, you could easily find yourself reusing it somewhere else. Or you could find out you want to make ad iPad app, which maybe supports multiwindows... anyway it could get bad. Spend your time learning how to properly architect the code, you’re gonna get all the benefits.